# How to reuse Helm templates across charts?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Here's how my Helm charts are organized:

```
helm-charts/
  service1/
    Chart.yaml
    templates/
      deployment.yaml
      ingress.yaml
      service.yaml
    values.yaml
  service2/
    Chart.yaml
    templates/
      deployment.yaml
      ingress.yaml
      service.yaml
    values.yaml
```

Now I have a couple of service which nearly share the same template *contents*, only some settings such as deployment *names* and deployment endpoints differ.

Is there a way to have a single reusable template *across* multiple Helm charts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Helm 3 has introduced the concept of [„Library Charts“](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/) which allows going DRY (don’t repeat yourself) with Helm charts. From its documentation:

> A library chart is a type of Helm chart that defines chart primitives or definitions which can be shared by Helm templates in other charts. This allows users to share snippets of code that can be re-used across charts, avoiding repetition and keeping charts DRY.

The complete manual can be found here: https://helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/

Comment: This doesn't really help, I have a bunch of files in /templates folder which read the values from values.yaml. I don't want to create in each helm chart a file .e.g deployment which has a reference to the lib. This is means I need to create all there files again and again. The best I could figure out is the create a folder template and symlink it into each folder containing a different helm chart

Comment: @FreshMike can you please explain how did the symlink or share more details about your setup? thanks

Comment: 4096 Oct 28 14:22 ..  
89     Oct 28 14:22 Chart.yaml  
13     Oct 28 14:22 templates -> ../_templates  
1060 Oct 28 14:25 values.yaml

Comment: I was thinking of using Library Charts, but it's so complex and doesn't solve DRY well enough from my perspective, I found it easier deploying a base chart with some default values to a private registry, then using it as dependency in my various services and just overriding some fields. I was trying to avoid doing that, but unfortunately other alternatives are more complex than just doing this.